# Assign ID to Form (Form Field) Opened by Field = Yes

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba

I have the following:

Form: sbfrm_lenderProducts

in which has a field: appraisalMethods

The field appraisalMethods has a combo-box value list with the answers: 'Yes; No; Depends'

I have the following code (VBA module) to open a form (frm_appraisalTypes) when the value to appraisalMethods = Yes

```
If Me.[appraisalMethods].Value = "YES" Then
   DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_appraisalTypes"
End If
```

It works fine. Was wondering if I would be able to add something to the code that will assign the record ID from sbfrm_lenderProducts to the opening form, frm_appraisalTypes.

For clarification, sbfrm_lenderProducts has a primary key lenderProductsID, and frm_appraisalTypes (a junction table) has the foreign key lenderProductsID. When the form is opened, I would like the foreign key lenderProductsID to match the primary key from the record being edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OpenArgs parameter.
In sbfrm_lenderProducts:

```
If Me.[appraisalMethods].Value = "YES" Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_appraisalTypes", , , , , , Me.[ID]
End If
```

In frm_appraisalTypes ID value will be available in `Me.OpenArgs`